# AlerDialog with Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-alertdialog

I try to design this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgyky.png)
But I don't know how to fix

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

     private Button btn;        
     private EditText et1;     
     private RadioButton A;        
     private RadioButton B;        
     private RadioButton O;         
     private RadioButton AB;        
     private RadioGroup rgroup;
```

Spinner part:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    final String[] lunch = {"Doctor", "Master", "Bachelor"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> lunchList = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lunch);
    spinner.setAdapter(lunchList);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    button.setOnClickListener(new Information());

}
```

Use button to show message:

```
private class Information implements OnClickListener
{

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        rgroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgroup);
        final String[] lunch = {"Doctor", "Master", "Bachelor"};
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        A = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.A);
        B = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.B);
        O = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.O);
        AB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.AB);

        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        int checkedRadioButtonId = rgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

This part is show RadioButton and Spinne messager:

```
        ad.setTitle("Information");
        switch (checkedRadioButtonId)
        {
            case R.id.A:
                ad.setMessage(input.getText() + " with blood type " + 
                A.getText() + " and " + lunch[?] + " degree");
                break;
            case R.id.B:
                ad.setMessage(input.getText() + " with blood type " + 
                B.getText() + " and " + lunch[?] + " degree");
                 break;
            case R.id.O:
                ad.setMessage(input.getText() + " with blood type " + 
                O.getText() + " and " + lunch[?] + " degree");
                break;
            case R.id.AB:
                ad.setMessage(input.getText() + " with blood type " + 
                AB.getText() + " and " + lunch[?] + " degree");
                break;
        }
        //ad.setTitle("Information");
        ad.setNeutralButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {

            }
        });

        ad.show();
        input.setText("");
    }

  }
}
```

But I don't know how to fix or add any on this :

```
  ad.setMessage(input.getText() + " with blood type " + A.getText() + " and 
  " + lunch[?] + " degree");
```

And it will be:
 Alice with blood type B and Doctor/Master/Bachelor(According I chose ) degree.

Answer (score 0):

Instead `input.getText();` or `A.getText();` use `input.getText().toString();` and `A.getText().toString();`

Comment: How about  lunch[ ]，this go to find which i chose and it will show what i want but i don't know how to let it show what i want

Comment: On Lynch you need an Integer index and not ?

Comment: yes, i try to use for loop but it always show me the third item(Bachelor), even i chose are Doctor or Master